# Issue with styled components causing 'useContext' error in React App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, styled-components, react-context

I can't use styled components because after i type this syntaxis:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div `
width: 600px;
margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
`;
```

Everything goes wrong and error with 'useContext' appears

P.S i started learning styled components in React and got stuck on this error.

I tried to remove node_module which was created after  terminal command npm install styled-components-didn't work out.Checked links to App.css file-nothing.
Here is code :

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import './App.css';

class WhoAmI extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      years: 27,
      position: ''
    };
  }

  nextYear = () => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      years: state.years + 1
    }));
  };

  commitInputChanges = (e, color) => {
    console.log(color);
    this.setState({
      position: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, surname, link } = this.props;
    const { position, years } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.nextYear}>+++</button>
        <h1>
          My name is {name}, surname - {surname}, age -{years}, position - {position}
        </h1>
        <a href={link}>My profile</a>
        <form>
          <span>Введите должность</span>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.commitInputChanges(e, 'some color');
            }}
          />
        </form> 
      </>
    );
  }
}
const Wrapper = styled.div `
width: 600px;
margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
`;
function App() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <WhoAmI name="John" surname="Smith" link="facebook.com" />
      <WhoAmI name="Alex" surname="Shepard" link="vk.com" />
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error Message:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40701:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42407:58
    at O (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42432:6)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20020:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22589:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24636:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9616:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9660:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9717:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29581:11)
```

-------UPDATE---------
I noticed that after i enter  in terminal 'npm install styled-components',second node_modules file appears outside of 'my-app' folder.I don't know how to make creating file by command to appear in original node_modules file

Comment: It seems like the error is not directly related to your usage of styled-components, but it might be occurring somewhere else in your code or dependencies. The error message points to an issue with `useContext` and is not directly related to the styled-components usage you provided.  


Clear the npm cache to make sure there are no cached files causing issues.
`npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @hcharles25 i found out that there are two node_modules in my parent folder.I don't know how to divert creation of new files by 'npm install styled-components' to the main original node_module file. If you know how to do it,I would appreciate that.

Comment: You need to `cd` into the `my-app` folder and then run `npm install styled-components`. Otherwise, `npm install` will create a new `npm` package instead of updating the existing one. You need to be in the same folder in your terminal as the original `node_modules` folder and your `package.json` file

Comment: @Wllow thank you very much my friend. It worked.Copy it in the answers,so i can pin it as the most correct one